# C# | Authorize.net AIM form submit progress indicator

Tags: c#, authorize.net

When I click the purchase button for the form I want the buttons text to change to processing... and have it be disabled while the form is waiting for a response back from authorize.net. Once the response comes back, return the button text to purchase and make it enabled. I do have two labels that are initially blank and once authorize.net returns a status it populates those labels with the correct response.

All of my authorize.net code is in a method called cc_Submit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that I could program against my update panel progress indicator.